# ¿Cómo calcular mostrar en consola el la cantidad faltante para llegar a un numero x?

Tags: javascript, operador

Tengo el siguiente problema para resolver: "los voluntarios se han dividido en 5 grupos con igual numero de miembros. Si algún grupo tiene menos de 5 personas, se deben reclutar mas voluntarios para cubrir los puestos.
Consigna: escribe un programa que lleve el numero de voluntarios y que indique a la consola cuántos voluntarios deben ser contratados para tener 5 grupos iguales.

Ejemplo de input: 24

ejemplo de output: 1

Explicación: el número mas cercano a 24 que es múltiplo de 5 es 25, por lo que necesitamos 1 voluntario mas (24+1=25) para conseguir 5 grupos iguales.

Estoy intentando con el siguiente código:

```js
let numeroVoluntarios = prompt("cuantos son?");

function faltantes(personas) {
  let resto = personas % 5;
  console.log(resto);
}

faltantes(numeroVoluntarios);
```

Pero este código me está dando el resto, y lo que necesito es el contrario de esto, lo faltante

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, me estoy volviendo loco jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo te falta ver que si el `resto` es mayor a cero, restárselo a `5`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let numeroVoluntarios = prompt("cuantos son?");

function faltantes(personas) {
  let grupos = 5;
  let resto = personas % grupos;
  let faltan = resto ? grupos - resto : resto;
  console.log(faltan);
}

faltantes(numeroVoluntarios);
```

Comment: Ohhh! Mil gracias, me ayudaste un monton!